# Centos PAM can't start httpd.service

Tags: centos, pam

I have OS **CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)**. I try just start almost pure httpd.service. I run command:

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

I try run this from my user and from *root* - it is not different. In my error log I noticed string:

```
pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
```

I thought that error was here. after my attempts to correct it, I tried replace in files **/etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac** and **/etc/pam.d/system-auth** Old string:

```
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
```

With new string:

```
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so quiet_success
```

this error string transform to

```
pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): no condition detected; module succeeded
```

I tried reinstall httpd - it didn't work. Now full error log on image. I just want to start my httpd.

[image]

Comment: Can you disable the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf` file and see if httpd works? To disable it, just rename file to another extension, say vhost.conf.bak.

Comment: @Haxiel Oh yearh. It started ok. It is very strange because .conf file example I take from https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache/install-and-configure-apache-on-centos-7/#configure-name-based-virtual-hosts I only set my ServerAdmin, 
 ServerName, ServerAlias.

Comment: @Vladimir To check what's wrong with that specific configuration file, you can enable it (rename it back to vhost.conf) and then run `apachectl configtest`. That should give you a more accurate error message.

Comment: @Haxial Ok. I have:AH00548: `NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:1
Syntax OK`

Comment: Okay, so you don't seem to have any configuration errors. Can you verify that the the directories specified in the virtual host configuration exist on the system? (/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/, /var/www/html/example.com/logs/).

Comment: @Haxiel Directories are exist, but log directory are empty. I think, that some troubles with my IP address. I don't have domain name - only IP address. When I run `curl https://ipinfo.io/ip` I have a normal IP 82.xxx.xxx.xx. But if I run `ip a` then I have IP 10.x.x.xx.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87746/discussion-between-haxiel-and-vladimir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in SELinux. In order to check this is our case or not run from root:

```
setenforce 0
```

Then

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

If the problem disappears then it is probably our case. For additional check: Add log debug level in main .conf httpd file. In my case  */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf* I added in this file:

```
LogLevel debug
```

Then set back setenforce to 1 and restart httpd. In error logs you may see some like this:

*(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log*
If you see this - that it is exactly our case. 
Then we need:

1. set setenforce to 0.
2. Change type of out log files with this command

   `chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t error.log`
3. set setenforce to 1.
4. restart httpd.service

After steps - all should be work fine.

P.S. Don't forget open your ports in firewall-cmd.

Comment: The reason SELinux is preventing you from saving your logs there is because the /var/www directory is defined in the policy as being for web content. Putting logs there is potentially dangerous.   Logs go in /var/log/httpd/ (or a sub directory within).

Comment: Also, if you *absolutely have to* put the logs in /var/www, you should amend the SELinux policy so it knows it.  Using “chcon” sets the attributes on the files that exist, but new files will not be labeled properly. Look at using “semanage fcontext ...” to set up a local policy for the context.

Comment: @jsbillings Putting logs in /var/www more comfortable and spread using, especially when using multiple virtual hosts. For example, see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7 They put logs in /var/www.

Comment: Well, their suggestions will break selinux. Digitalocean regularly suggests turning off security features, that’s why they have so many compromised servers. You could always keep the logs in /var/log/httpd/example.com/ and create a symlink in your /var/www directory if you find it hard to remember.